# Operator overloading with macros in c++

Tags: c++, macros, printf, operator-overloading, cout

Hi i have a sample program on macros,

```
#include<iostream>
#define ABS(a) (a) < 0 ? -(a) : (a)

int main(){
    printf("%d",ABS(-1));
    std::cout<<ABS(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above prgram i was trying to subsititute -1 with a in **MACRO** but if i try to print it with **printf** it works!, But if i use **cout** it throws up an error. I know it is related to overloading of **"<<"** operator, But i dont know the exact reason. Please can someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2678   binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  practice_project    C:\Users\source\repos\practice_project\Source.cpp   10
```

This was the error caused to be specific? So my question is not on why i should not use **MACROS** , my question is why **printf** gave me the answer and why not cout?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: "*it throws up an error*": Please explain what the error is. Also, do not use macros for something like that. Use a function template instead. There is already an implementation in the standard library, called `std::abs`, as well.

Comment: Start by reading the error message.

Comment: At the time when compilers weren't that good at optimizing as nowadays, macros like this had their use. But nowadays the situations where you want to use macros are really rare (e.g. to only enable code for certain platforms or compilers) . In general, if you are new to c++ you shouldn't use them.

Comment: @walnut i know i was just trying out things, only thing i wanted is why it behaved like that? and the error was regarding operator overloading itself??

Comment: @t.niese i know these things about macro i wanted to check why cout behaved like that while not printf? i am not new to c++. All i wanted to check why i got an error on operator overloading and why cout behaved like that??

Comment: @Karthikgr There is nothing related to operator overloading in your question. You just are not taking care of the operator precedence of `<<` relative to the other operators involved in your macro replacement.

Comment: @walnut i have edited the question and my question is why it worked for printf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros do a search and replace **before** compiling, so `printf("%d",ABS(-1));` becomes `printf("%d", (a) < 0 ? -(a) : (a))`, and the `std::cout<<ABS(-1);` becomes `std::cout<<(-1) < 0 ? -(-1) : (-1)`, and then the compiling is done.

`<<` ha a higher precedence then `<` so the `std::cout<<(-1) < 0 ? -(-1) : (-1)` is equal to `(std::cout<<(-1)) < 0 ? -(-1) : (-1)`.

In `printf` there is no such rule to apply as the `,` in the `printf` that is the separator of the arguments and not an operator.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that macros are pure text substitution, so the cout becomes:

std::cout<<(-1) < 0 ? -(-1) : (-1);

Comment: i know this very well, but what i wanted is why cout threw operator overloading error and why printf successfully gave answer for this?